# MySQL Order by fixed positions

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column named fixed_position. For some items this is filled with an int, other rows have a null value.

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT id, fixed_position, intvalue (calculated in a subquery)
FROM content_items
ORDER BY intvalue DESC
```

So the result is ordered by intvalue DESC. But I want to have a row with `fixed_position=12` always on 12th position in the result set.

Is this possible and how can I do this?

Example data:

```
+------+-------------------+-------------+
|  ID  | fixed_position    |   intvalue  |
+------+-------------------|-------------+
|  x   |       null        |       17    |
|  x   |       null        |       14    |
|  x   |       null        |       11    |
|  x   |       null        |       9     |
|  x   |        3          |       6     |
|  x   |        2          |       3     |
|  x   |       null        |       1     |
```

Desired output:

```
+------+-------------------+-------------+
|  ID  | fixed_position    |   intvalue  |
+------+-------------------|-------------+
|  x   |       null        |       17    |
|  x   |        2          |       3     |
|  x   |        3          |       6     |
|  x   |       null        |       14    |
|  x   |       null        |       11    |
|  x   |       null        |       9     |
|  x   |       null        |       1     |
```

Comment: Please amend your question with example data and desired output.

Comment: Only for 12 or for all values in this column?

Comment: How do you get the fixed position? What if you have 11 or less rows returned?

Comment: @Tim3880, this value will be added manually, and it will always be less then the amount of rows returned by the query

Comment: I have finally fixed it in PHP, get the result with the fixed positions and the result without fixed positions, and merge it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY` clause to assign a higher sort value to your fixed_position null cases so they float to the bottom of the list. For example:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN intvalue IS NULL then 999 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly then the row with fixed_position = 12 will be in the first position, not the 12th.

Comment: If you sort ascending with the above syntax, it should push the null values to the bottom of the list. Is there a particular reason you need to sort descending?

Comment: Oh. I don't think you *can* accomplish that, based on the criteria you laid out.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running this as temp query with  ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (order by" from which you can update with case statement, to update fixedposition=12 where row number=12

Comment: I'm trying, but then I will get two rows with position 12, so the next fixed_position will shift one row.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is kind of odd. But you can try this:

```
set @pos =0; 
select * from (
 SELECT @pos := @pos +1 pos, id, intvalue, fixed_position
 from (select id, fixed_position, id+11 as intvalue
   FROM content_items
   ORDER BY intvalue DESC)
  e
 ) f
 order by case when fixed_position>0 then fixed_position else pos end;
```

It's still not working as you requested. It just gives you a closer order. To get more closer order, you need move all entries with the calculated order in your own defined positions to the bottom (or at least to the last predefined positions).